# Add line after some text

Tags: css

I'm trying to get a line to sit after some text.

```
.dash span {
 background-color: white;
 padding-right: 5px;
 }

.dash:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 height: 0.5em;
 border-top: 1px solid #000;
 z-index: -1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pkm5r/62/

Comment: Like that - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tbndktqf/)

Comment: Your requirements are way too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simple remove `height: 0.5em;` from .`dash::after`.

```
.dash:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkm5r/64/)**